# How can I reconnect all sessions/tabs at once in WinSCP?

Tags: winscp

How can I reconnect all sessions/tabs at once in WinSCP? I would prefer not to have to reconnect each tab one by one:

[image]

Comment: It's not possible. You can [request the feature](https://winscp.net/forum/viewforum.php?f=4) :)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks, done: https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=26877&start=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Martin Prikryl (WinSCP developer) indicated that currently it isn't possible. I created a feature request: https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=26877&start=0